# How can I style <button> so it is visibly like <span> without slowing down rendering?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, accessibility

I am thinking about replacing `<span>` with `<button>` for accessibility reasons. I want the element to render just like now. The `CSS` for this looks something like the below code. (Please add to it if you see something missing.)

```css
button {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Since there are very many such spans in my app (think thousands), I wonder if this slows down rendering (in Chrome or in newer Firefox)?

Please tell me the reason why it slows down or does not slow down rendering.

---

EDIT: I got a comment that it might be hard to understand why I am doing this. It is a good comment!

The reason is that if I use `<button>` instead of `<span>`, I don't have to add a keyboard handler for the element and make the element focusable. It is, in most cases, done automatically by the browser for `<button>`. (This is required for accessibility.)

Comment: So it would be a good idea to edit your question and explain why you think a page with thousands of buttons would be good for accessibility.

Comment: @MrLister I just explained what good `button` could do. The reason for the many clickable elements depends on the application (and I don't think there is any reason to explain that).

Comment: This will result in massive accessibility issues, each one of your spans is going to be read out as a button to someone with a screen reader and make your site unusable. Could you provide a reason for why you are actually doing this (screen shot, code snippet or the actual use case) and i will come up with a suitable alternative for you to manage focus as at present you are probably making things worse by mistake.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thanks, I see. Then it is a bit too complicated for this post. I may try to contact you at your web site instead.

Comment: Go for it, if the page is publicly accessible I just need the link to understand what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since there are very many such spans in my app (think thousands) I wonder if this slows down rendering etc (in Chrome in newer Firefox)?

Nope it does not slow the rendering. Browsers do use internally CSS definitions.

> for accessibility reasons

WCAG guideline [Non-text Contrast](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html) provides interesting information about color contrast between input controls and adjacent text which you should take care of, as you remove all boundaries.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I expect, but I wondered if missed something.

Comment: Regarding the text contrast I am just looking at the Accessibility Inspector in Firefox. Some tests made me wonder what part of it is reliable yet.